# What is the best way to toggle two hidden radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two hidden radio buttons and one visible button. Clicking this button should toggle which button is checked.

I can achieve this using if statements and just setting radio button (ID) = checked.

But how can this be achieved with the least ammount of code?

**update**
To sattisfy those who's got nothing better to do than complain about missing code. Altough, I don't see how this will make the question more `constructive`.

```
<div class="switch">
    <input id="check1" type="radio" name="search" class="rbtn-search" checked="checked" value="brand" />
    <input id="check2" type="radio" name="search" class="rbtn-search" checked="" value="store" />
</div>


$('.switch').click(function(){
  // Switch the radio buttons here
})
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you've got

Comment: 3k rep, 281 questions and no code/attempts?? -1. You aren't new.

Comment: @truth - What are you wining about? This is not a question about why my code is not working. The question is what jQuery code would be the most effective, irrelevant to what code I have.

Comment: This is not whining: There is no "real" answer to this question. "Best way" is a subjective question and unless there *is* code provided that demonstrates an actual problem to be solved, this is `Not Constructive`. This should be asked, with real code, on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Took the words right out of my mouth.

Comment: Ok, I give in. I updated my qyestion and added code. Did this make the question `less subjective`? And I've never heard of codereview.stackexchage.com, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you have not, [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). This is not hard to understand; being cheeky and "putting code in the question" is stupid and self-defeating. The only problem you have is you don't already know which is "best", with the subjectiveness of the answer you select being "whichever you like most". There is no "better". If you have a *problem* with the performance of a piece of code that can be replicated, *that* is the type of question SO is built on answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfdnh/16/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  ​<input type="radio" checked="checked">
  <input type="radio">
  <a class="button" href="#">button</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#container .button').click(function () {
    $('#container :radio').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: You can use `$(':radio').each(...` istead.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this solution. Why can't we use `prop` instead of `attr`? I tried and that doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `$('#container :radio')` instead of `$('#container input[type="radio"]')` too ..

Answer (score 2):

You could use map:

```
 <input type="radio" checked="checked">
 <input type="radio">
 <a id="btn">I'm a bbutton</a>​


jQuery("#btn").click(function() {
    jQuery(":radio").map(function() { this.checked = !this.checked; });        
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc6wZ/3/)

Comment: Looks like this is the least ammount of code that can be used :) Unfortunately I'm not able to make it work on my site :(

Comment: @Steven That's weird, if you want to provide some code I'll be happy to help. Otherwise, check the selectors ( `"#btn"` and `":radio"`), it should work if those are right :)

Comment: See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc6wZ/4/

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/w7ZjG/1/ :)

Comment: @Steven did that work for you?

Comment: @Steven I know I'm annoying, but could you please upvote me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    $(':radio').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try;

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(':radio').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(':radio').attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

Here is the working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfdnh/6/)**

or this way using class;

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('.radiobtn').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$('.radiobtn').attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

Here is the working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfdnh/14/)